# How to get the right values from I2C device?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, unsigned, signed, i2c

I am trying to read from an I2C slave with the Raspberry Pi as the master.

The data at the slave looks like this:

```
uint8_t i2cdata[4];
i2cdata[0] = 0xDE; //Binary: 11011110
i2cdata[1] = 0xAD; //Binary: 10101101
i2cdata[2] = 0xBE; //Binary: 10111110
i2cdata[3] = 0xEF; //Binary: 11101111
```

Now i am trying to read the values using the wiringPi-Lib:

```
int fd = wiringPiI2CSetup(0x28);
uint8_t v1 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0);
uint8_t v2 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,1);
uint8_t v3 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,2);
uint8_t v4 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,3);
printf("V1: 0x%X\n",v1);
printf("V2: 0x%X\n",v2);
printf("V3: 0x%X\n",v3);
printf("V4: 0x%X\n",v4);
```

The Output is:

```
V1: 0x5E; //Binary: 01011110
V2: 0x2D; //Binary: 00101101
V3: 0x3E; //Binary: 00111110
V4: 0x6F; //Binary: 01101111
```

To me this seems to be a signed / unsigned problem. If i am using the oscilloscope to monitor the bus, the correct values 0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF are displayed.

Comment: Did you mean for all of your `i2cdata` indices to be 0?

Comment: No, of course not. This was a copy&paste mistake..

Comment: Are you sure the `MSB` is part of the `int`?  I know sometimes the `MSB` is used to indicate something else.  Otherwise your original theory seems correct that it is signed/unsigned issue.

Comment: It looks correct to me. `wiringPiI2CReadReg8` returns an integer though. So, what happens if you change `uint8_t v1 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0);` to `int v1 = wiringPiI2CReadReg8(fd,0);`. Probably not the problem, but maybe worth a try. That way you could also treat errors (i.e if the value is negative).

Comment: That doesn't change anything :/

Comment: What happens if one of the registers has the top bit clear?  The read function will return a negative `int` on failure, which you will not be able to detect if you store the result in a `uint8_t`, but assuming that is not happening, the code looks ok.  This is the first bit after the bus has changed direction, and being a 1, it will require the bus to charge up through the pull-up. Are you sure the waves on the oscope look correct?